# State of modifier keys in fullscreen flash content

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard, fullscreen

I have a small browser-based tool which works best in fullscreen. I'm adding in keyboard shortcuts, but I've run into a limitation of Flash: it blocks most keyboard access when in fullscreen mode.

The `SPACE` key does work, and since I've only got a few commands which are semi-related it would be OK to make them all work with the space key (`SPACE`, `alt+SPACE`, etc). *But* the modifier keys don't get sent in fullscreen mode either!

Is there a way around this? (some other way of reading the modifier keys' states?)

(I've heard about interactive fullscreen mode in flash player 11, but this is no good for me; most of the audience are on older versions and I don't want the "allow" message box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the interactive fullscreen mode for Flash Player 11.3 or later is your only option.  Othherwise you're limited to, I believe, the space and arrow keys.  However, I wouldn't be too concerned with the `Allow` dialog that appears at the top of the screen when entering full screen mode as it's been quite common for a while now - users will expect it.

You might also consider distributing an AIR application instead of a browser-resident flash application if you want to avoid the keybaord limitations and the dialog popup.

Comment: I already have one "allow" box because I access the webcam, a second is just too much (this is a tool, not an app, and users *will* give up). For similar reasons, forcing users to install an application is also not an option.

Comment: (I'll be switching to HTML5 for a long-term solution but HTML5's webcam support doesn't have a wide enough audience yet)

Comment: I'm not really versed with the new JavaScript APIs, but I'd be surprised, and a little worried, if any website could active your webcam without the users consent via a dialog popup.

Comment: Off-topic but: Yes, it still shows a message, but it is 1) a *much* nicer looking message (Chrome uses a top bar, like the one for location tracking), and 2) I know I can do the keyboard stuff in HTML's fullscreen mode (so it won't need 2 popups)